# pip install and sudo on mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I wanted to reinstall virtualenv. I successfully did:

`pip uninstall virtualenv`

Then to reinstall I tried:

`pip install virtualenv`

Which resulted in the error: `error: /lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py: Permission denied`

So I tried:

`sudo pip install virtualenv`

Which resulted in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

**Q1: Why would sudo lead to such a problem?** I've read that this error is caused by not having setuptools installed properly. But why only with the sudo command? Does that lead python to look elsewhere for its resources?

Some details about my setup:

I'm on MacOS 10.9.4.

I'm not sure why but I seem to have python set up in two locations:

1. /usr/local/lib/

   - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
   - /usr/local/lib/python3.3/
2. /lib

   - /lib/python2.7/
   - /lib/python3.3/

**Q2: Why the two locations?** From what I can tell pip and pip3 install things in the second location. Perhaps I've got too many versions of python running around?

Heres a print of sys.path from the interactive python console:

```
['',
 '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg',
 '/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/lib/python2.3/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/david/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/lib/python2.3/site-packages']
```

Comment: `brew doctor` would probably be a good thing to run.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure I understand exactly the source of my original problem (Don't know the answer to Q1), I did fix it by uninstalling/unlinking Python with Homebrew, then setting everything back up following [THIS](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) Tutorial. The main lessons I got were:

- Macs come with a version of python already installed. This is why there were python installations in `/lib`. I had also installed python with Homebrew, which created those second installations in the `/usr/local/lib/`. After a while of not being careful about which I was using/installing packages to caught up with me.
- virtualenv is a great and **easy** way to localize and isolate version and dependency needs to individual projects. I put off using it because I thought it was probably complicated, but it isn't and it probably would have saved me this trouble.